# How to make anchor links in Fixed header with height 200px?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a fixed header with height 200px.
How to make anchor links in Fixed header.
Now the menu is not work good.
You can see my code below:

```css
.fluid {
  clear: both;
  margin-left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
/* Mobile Layout: 480px and below. */

body {
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, "Heiti TC", "Microsoft JhengHei", "Microsoft Yahei", "PMingLiU", sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.gridContainer {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: 1.1375%;
  padding-right: 1.1375%;
  clear: none;
  float: none;
  width: auto;
}
#header {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #FF6600;
}
/* header - navigation */

#subnav {
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #1BBC9B;
  font-size: 120%;
}
#navmenu ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: 0%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  width: 650px;
}
#navmenu li {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
}
#navmenu a {
  color: #294C52;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#navmenu li a {
  border-right: 1px solid #294C52;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
#navmenu li:last-child a {
  border-right: 1px solid #576979;
  /* no border on last list item */
}
#navmenu li:first-child a {
  background-color: #294C52;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
#navmenu a:hover,
nav a:active {
  background-color: #1BBC9B;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
#content {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 1px;
}
#section1 {
  background-color: #294C52;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 198px;
}
#section2 {
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
}
#section3 {
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
}
#section4 {
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  margin-left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
#content-about-org-left {
  width: 48.1012%;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  float: left;
  clear: none;
}
#content-about-org-centre {
  width: 48.1012%;
  margin-left: 1.2658%;
  clear: none;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  float: right;
}
#content-about-org-right {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
#section5 {
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
}
/* content - typography */

.content-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #294C52;
  text-indent: -25px;
  font-size: 100%;
  line-height: 173%;
}
.content-list-bold {
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 110%;
  color: #294C52;
}
.content-title {
  background-color: #903233;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding-top: 3px;
}
.content-p-white {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  text-align: justify;
  line-height: 25px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
.content-p-black {
  color: #294C52;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  text-align: justify;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-size: 100%;
}
.content-p-black-b {
  color: #294C52;
  font-weight: bolder;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 110%;
}
```

```html
<div class="gridContainer clearfix">
  <header id="header">

    <nav id="subnav" class="fluid">
      <ul id="navmenu">
        <li><a href="#section1" title="成立背景">成立背景</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#section2" title="協會使命">協會使命</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#section3" title="營運模式">營運模式</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#section4" title="協會組織">協會組織</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#section5" title="活動及刊物">活動及刊物</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <!--end of header-->
  <!--start of content-->
  <div class="fluid" id="content">
    <div id="section1" class="fluid ">
      <p class="content-p-white">《2013年香港殘疾人士貧窮情況報告》顯示介乎18至64歲適齡工作的殘疾人士的貧窮率為22.4%，遠較相同年齡群的整體貧窮率10.5%為高。再者，按經濟活動身分劃分，近18萬名的殘疾適齡工作人士當中，只有39.1%有從事經濟活動，遠低於整體人口中同年齡層的72.8%。</p>
      <p class="content-p-white">於2013年3月初，一群熱心人士包括郭鍵勳博士、謝俊謙教授及伍杏修先生等有意建立一個各方協作平台，改善殘疾人士的就業困難。</p>
      <p class="content-p-white">資訊科技易達協會有限公司 Accessible IT Development Association Limited (AIDA) 於2014年11月正式註冊成立。</p>
      <!--<div id="secttion1-bg"></div>-->

    </div>
    <!--end of section1-->
    <div id="section2" class="fluid">
      <article>
        <h2 class="content-title">&nbsp;&nbsp;協會使命</h2>
        <p class="content-p-black">資訊科技易達協會是一個社會企業致力提供專業資訊科技服務，同時為嚴重殘疾人士提供培訓及工作機會，讓學員可選擇在家居從事資訊科技相關工作；協會全力推動無障礙軟件開發，協助社會資訊共融。</p>
      </article>
    </div>
    <!--end of section2-->
    <div id="section3" class="fluid">
      <article>
        <h2 class="content-title">&nbsp;&nbsp;營運模式</h2>
        <figure>
          <img src="images/2-about-us_03.jpg" alt="營運模式示意圖" class="alignRight" title="營運模式示意圖" />
        </figure>
        <p class="content-p-black">全面利用現代通訊科技的便利，解決殘疾人士面對指定工作地點的限制，讓他們可選擇在家居或院舍工作，同時得到必要的護理。AIDA選擇網頁開發作為起步點，由「無障礙學堂」(Barrier-Free School) 及業界專業義工負責培訓學員，讓他們掌握指定技術。</p>
        <p class="content-p-black">AIDA會承接工作項目，將項目分拆，然後將組件分配給技術程度不同的學員，並會密切督導整個項目的進行。AIDA已經與本地多間知名網頁開發公司結為合作伙伴，致力確保AIDA的所有服務均符合市場要求。AIDA會以殘疾友善機構的工作項目作為開始，當累積一定成功往績後，會推廣至主流市場。</p>
      </article>
    </div>
    <!--end of section3-->
    <div id="section4" class="fluid">
      <article>
        <h2 class="content-title">&nbsp;&nbsp;協會組織</h2>
        <div id="content-about-org-left" class="fluid">
          <ul class="content-list">
            <li class="content-list-bold">名譽贊助人</li>
            <li>謝俊謙教授</li>
            <li class="content-list-bold">主席</li>
            <li>郭鍵勳博士</li>
            <li class="content-list-bold">副主席</li>
            <li>劉海軍先生</li>
            <li class="content-list-bold">義務秘書</li>
            <li>伍杏修先生</li>
            <li class="content-list-bold">義務司庫</li>
            <li>郭皓君女士</li>
            <li class="content-list-bold">核數師</li>
            <li></li>
            <li class="content-list-bold">義務法律顧問</li>
            <li>林子絪女士</li>
            <li class="content-list-bold">義務總幹事</li>
            <li>蘇炳坤先生</li>
            <li class="content-list-bold">諮詢委員及指導</li>
            <li></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="content-about-org-centre" class="fluid">
          <ul class="content-list">
            <li class="content-list-bold">董事</li>
            <li>張健輝先生</li>
            <li>郭鍵勳博士</li>
            <li>郭皓君女士</li>
            <li>劉海軍先生</li>
            <li>羅偉祥先生</li>
            <li>伍杏修先生</li>
            <li>吳家榮博士</li>
            <li>蘇炳坤先生</li>
            <li>謝俊謙教授</li>
            <li>黃婉冰女士</li>
            <li>游寶榮先生</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="content-about-org-right" class="fluid">
          <ul class="content-list">
            <li class="content-list-bold">工作團隊</li>
            <li>王乃東 王迪清 江啟暉 利詠然 李俊輝</li>
            <li>李豪飛 冼永健 何浚彥 施嶸傑 翁文菁</li>
            <li>茹文祥 郭寧 章世恒 曾志豪 曾鈴茵</li>
            <li>黃新陽 蔡冀逵 鄭建慧 盧兆豐</li>
          </ul>
          <p>
            <img src="images/2-about-us_06.jpg" alt="工作團隊成員相片" title="工作團隊成員相片" />
          </p>
        </div>
      </article>
    </div>
    <!--end of section4-->
    <div id="section5" class="fluid">
      <article>
        <h2 class="content-title">&nbsp;&nbsp;活動及刊物</h2>
        <ul class="content-list">
          <li class="content-list-bold">新春團拜</li>
          <li>日期︰2015年3月14日(星期六)</li>
          <li>地點︰金鐘添馬公園添馬茶座愛烘焙餐廳</li>
          <li>時間︰下午4:00- 5:30</li>
        </ul>
        <hr>
        <ul class="content-list">
          <li class="content-list-bold">第一次周年大會</li>
          <li>日期︰2015年3月14日(星期六)</li>
          <li>地點︰金鐘添馬公園添馬茶座愛烘焙餐廳</li>
          <li>時間︰下午3:30- 4:00</li>
        </ul>
        <hr>
        <ul class="content-list">
          <li class="content-list-bold">協會發展成長分享會</li>
          <li>日期︰2015年2月3日(星期二)</li>
          <li>地點︰金鐘添馬公園添馬茶座愛烘焙餐廳</li>
          <li>時間︰上午11:00- 下午4:00</li>
          <li>內容：</li>
          <li>1. Delifrance午膳</li>
          <li>2. 匯報協會最新發展，就大家感興趣的事務進行商討</li>
          <li>3. IT人Ben Wong 個人經歷分享</li>
          <li>4. 參觀香港大學校園或自由活動</li>
        </ul>
        <hr>
      </article>
    </div>
    <!--end of section5-->
  </div>
  <!--end of content-->

</div>
<!--end of gridContainer-->
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGgbKN

Comment: what exactly does not work? The header is too high? I'd choose `height: 85px`

Comment: You cannot do this just with anchor html links. You have to use JS to make it happen. Add a click event when the anchor clicked attr the href and send to the anchor minus 200 or so pixels from top. I'll give you later an example.

Comment: my design is 200px.
cannot move back to section1.

Comment: Sorry @LoSiuFung now it's ok there was an error at aTag and now it;s ok. Please check it and let me know if everything was ok.

Comment: Did the updated answer helped you?

Comment: still not work. the position of section move wrongly. And it cannot move back to section 1

Comment: But in your codepen it's ok with the edit provided in my answer. Are you sure?

Comment: @LosiuFung just added a fiddle in my question. Please verify if everything is ok for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the places you want to send the links (wher the anchors are). For ex:

```
<div id="section2" class="fluid" name="section2">
```

Then change your links:

```
<a href="#" class="#link" onClick="scrollToAnchor('section2');" title="成立背景">成立背景</a>
```

And add this script to your page footer:

```
var menuContainer = $('header').height();

function scrollToAnchor(anchorName){
    var aTag = $("div[name='"+ anchorName +"']");
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: aTag.offset().top - menuContainer },'slow');
}
```

Finally here's a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x2skzp1p/
Cheers

Comment: Why not grab the height of the header and use that as a variable

Comment: Ok @LoSiuFung , check my new aproach then. I have just update the answer

Comment: Did you try the update? When i'm implementing this to your codepen it works correctly

Comment: Sorry @LoSiuFung now it's ok there was an error at aTag and now it;s ok. Please check it and let me know if everything was ok.

Comment: Added a working fiddle to verify it's ok. Please verify you have already include jQuery...